# "cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log" when upgrading from Postgresql 9.1 to 9.3

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, pg-upgrade

I keep on getting the above error whenever I run the following command via a postgres user.

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade \
   -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/ \
   -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/ \
   -d /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main \
   -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

> **cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log Failure, exiting**

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. Both Postgresql 9.1 and 9.3 are running properly.

Answer (score 91):

Make sure that you run this command from a directory that is writable by the `postgres` user, like `/tmp` or `/var/lib/postgresql`:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade ...
```

Answer (score 0):

#run pg_upgrade command in new data directory path.

Ex: bash-4.2$ pwd

/var/lib/pgsql/11/data

bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/10/data --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-11/bin --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-11/bin -c

Comment: Format your answer with proper code block

Answer (score 0):

fix with chown:
chown postgres:postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin