# pg_upgrade on Windows cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-server-2008-r2, pg-upgrade

I'm trying to run pg_upgrade on Windows 2008R2, but I'm getting the error:

> cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log Failure, exiting

I saw a similar question for Linux at [23216734](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216734/cannot-write-to-log-file-pg-upgrade-internal-log-when-upgrading-from-postgresq) which explains that the issue is with permissions, but it doesn't help with Windows as I do not have a user named `postgres`

Same goes for the [pg_upgrade docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html), which mention a `postgres` user:

> RUNAS /USER:postgres "CMD.EXE"

But again, I do not have such a user, and am trying to run this command as Administrator so I don't understand why I would have no permission.  I even tried to do

```
RUNAS /USER:Administrator "CMD.EXE"
```

And run pg_upgrade in the new command prompt, but am getting the same error.

Also, I am not sure which directory needs permissions?  Where is the process trying to write `pg_upgrade_internal.log` to?

---

More details:

The command I'm running is:

```
C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin>pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir=E:\PGSQL_data --new-datadir=E:\PGSQLData\pgsql-9.5 --old-bindir=C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.4.5.3\bin --new-bindir=C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin
```

From the same command prompt that gives the error I ran the following commands and they all worked, creating an empty file in the respective directories, so write permissions to the directories that are passed to pg_upgrade are allowed:

```
C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin>type nul > E:\PGSQL_data\_test_write_permission.txt
C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin>type nul > E:\PGSQLData\pgsql-9.5\_test_write_permission.txt
C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin>type nul > C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.4.5.3\bin\_test_write_permission.txt
C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin>type nul > C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin\_test_write_permission.txt
```

So now I'm even more puzzled than before...

---

Even more details:

I see that the command to create the internal log file is at [/src/bin/pg_upgrade/option.c#L101](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_upgrade/option.c#L101)

Which calls `fopen_priv(INTERNAL_LOG_FILE, "a")` defined at 
[/src/bin/pg_upgrade/file.c#L243](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_upgrade/file.c#L243)

But I'm not sure to which directory it is trying to write.  If I would know that then I can check the permissions on that directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the complete command line that you use to run `pg_upgrade`. You should not run that as Administrator, a regular user is enough, but you have to make sure that the access rights on **both** data directories are setup correctly!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I updated the question to show the full command line.  I am logged on to Windows as the Administrator so the directories should be accessible to the user account.  Do you know where does pg_upgrade try to save pg_upgrade_internal.log to?

Comment: No idea. I just did an upgrade from 9.4 to 9.5 with a regular user account and everything worked fine, so I guess the file is stored in some temp directory of the current user. I had to quote the path to the `.exe` and I used the wrong way of quoting the path which then resulted in very strange errors. That's why I asked for the full command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I quoted paths on other PG tools, e.g. `initdb` it failed, so I try to avoid that.  For good measure, I tried now to quote all the paths, as well as changing the `\` separator to '/', but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So the source code comment at [/src/bin/pg_upgrade/file.c#L243](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_upgrade/file.c#L243) `/* fopen() file with no group/other permissions */` gave me an idea.

I created a temp folder at C:\temp and gave *Write* permissions to *Everyone*, and then ran pg_upgrade from that directory, i.e.

`C:\temp>C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin\pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir=E:\PGSQL_data --new-datadir=E:\PGSQLData\pgsql-9.5 --old-bindir=C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.4.5.3\bin --new-bindir=C:\Apps\postgresql\pgsql-9.5.0\bin`

Whereas before I was trying to run pg_upgrade from the working directory `%PGSQL%\bin` which did not have a Write permissions to Everyone.

Now I don't get the `cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log` error anymore.

The [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) actually say `pg_upgrade requires write permission in the current directory.`

Comment: yep, have to be in a temp folder, and then call the full path to the p_upgrade utility, thanks