# psql indicates different server version

Tags: postgresql, psql, ubuntu-16.04

Today I was prompted to upgrade my OS from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.  Generally speaking, it went smoothly.  However, I did receive error messages indicating that the upgrade of PostgreSQL from 9.3 to 9.5 did not succeed.  I eventually was able to install postgresql-9.5 and have verified that I see my previously created databases and tables.

However, when I use the `psql` command to access a database called `hierarchy` as follows, I get some unfamiliar output:

```
$ psql hierarchy jkeenan
psql (9.5.3, server 9.3.13)
Type "help" for help.
```

Does this indicate that part of my PostgreSQL setup (broadly speaking) was **not** upgraded to 9.5?

**Update:**  Once inside `psql` I can say `SELECT version();` and get this output:

```
 PostgreSQL 9.3.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4, 64-bit
```

How would I perform this upgrade?  Is the difference between the `psql` version and the "server" version something I should be concerned about?

Other data which might be helpful in diagnosis:

```
$ createdb --version
createdb (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it proved very helpful.  For reference, here are the points where there was some confusion.

1. In the older, 9.3 installation, in pg_hba.conf, I had: `local all postgres md5` (for reasons I can't recall right now).  I had to switch that back to `local all postgres peer` to proceed.

2. After `sudo su postgres`, you have to switch to a directory writable by user `postgres`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216734/cannot-write-to-log-file-pg-upgrade-internal-log-when-upgrading-from-postgresq.

3. I had to use `\` line separators when pasting the `pg_upgrade` command.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe link in your comment is not accessible. Could you provide the correct link?

Comment: @ABN I don't know if that very blog still exists. Essentially, you either have to dump the cluster and restore it into the higher version, or you have to run `pg_upgrade`. I recommend the PostgreSQL documentation.